# How to rename MySQL tables to uppercase in SQL

Tags: mysql, rename

My current approach looks like this:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name, COUNT(table_name) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'dbname';

OPEN cur;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur INTO name, count;
IF done = count THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
ELSE
    SET done = done + 1;
END IF;
  IF SUBSTR(name, 1, 4) = 'old_' THEN
    ALTER TABLE name RENAME TO UPPER(SUBSTR(name,5));
  ELSE
    ALTER TABLE name RENAME TO CONCAT('old_', name);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

I'm running MySQL 5.1.46 on my local machine.

Comment: What exactly is the problem which needs solving?

Comment: What Zirak said...MySQL is not case sensitive so renaming the tables will not make an iota of difference.

Comment: mySQL *is* case sensitive if the underlying file system is, but I still can't think of a reason to do this

Answer (score -1):

MySQL is case insensitive for database scheme by default. See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) for that. But you can enable case sensitivity from `my.cnf`.

However InnoDB stores table names only with lowercase on Windows. See [documentation](http://mysql.openmirrors.org/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Comment: Not true. From that manual page: `This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.`

Comment: Note that case sensitivity can be disabled from `my.cnf` as I said.

Comment: I got that option in 'my.cnf' enabled and i need it. And i have these lowercase Tables, that my application needs in uppercase. Is it possible to this just with MySQL?

Comment: why not disable that option and make them case insensitive?